# Pysmb SMBConnection listPath function - Can I use Regex in the pattern parameter?

Tags: python, regex, pysmb

Regarding the listpath() method of [SMBConnection class](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smbconnection-class) in pysmb and following on from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141485/how-to-set-pattern-matching-in-pythons-smbcoonect-listpath-function).

Using the SMBConnect listPath function pattern parameter, is it possible to specify more than one pattern?

Example:

This code only returns files from a Samba share that have a .pdf extension

```
files = newConn.listPath('C$', '/' + 'testing', pattern='*.pdf')
```

But I want to specify more than one pattern.. e.g: .pdf OR .doc

I tried using a regex like this but it doesn't work.

```
files = newConn.listPath('C$', '/' + 'testing', pattern="'^.*\.(pdf|doc)$'")
```

Any help much appreciated!

---

### Update

As per the accepted answer, it is not possible to filter on more than one file extension. There is a [work around in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141485/how-to-set-pattern-matching-in-pythons-smbcoonect-listpath-function) that gives the functionality I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pysmb follows the SMB protocol closely. Unfortunately, the SMB protocol only supports wildcards but does not support regular expressions in the search pattern.